# Apache custom error page

Tags: apache, .htpasswd, apache2.4

I'm trying to use htpassd for my sites, and whitelist a couple of ips. This works perfectly, but if the user presses the cancel button, it shows the standard apache 401 error page.

With ErrorDocument I am supposed to cusomize it, so I placed a html file auth.html in /var/www/auth.html. If I go to my.server.ip.address/auth.html I see the page.

But in combination with ErrorDocument I get the standard message with:

```
Additionally, a 401 Authorization Required error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

How can I debug this, nothing shows up in /var/log/apache/error.log

This is the piece of apache conf I use to set it all up, it's included via /etc/apache2/conf.d on my debian machine.

```
<Directory /var/www/ >
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
</Directory>

<Directory /home/goodmorning >
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthName "Wachtwoord opvragen kan via support@company.nl"
AuthUserFile /home/hg/htpasswd
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
Allow from w.x.y.z
Allow from w.x.y.z
Allow from w.x.y.z
Satisfy Any

</Directory>
ErrorDocument 401 /auth.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that /auth.html is readable by the apache user

and this document should not be in protected directory.

Comment: It is, I even did chmod 777

Comment: is this error page  in protection directory or somewhere else